# How to exclude dict elements while sorting with lambda with respect to function value?

Tags: python, sorting, lambda

I'm using lambda to sort a dict.

Following is what I have:

```
sorted = sorted(foo_dict, key=lambda foo: my_method(foo, bar))
```

It works but I need to exclude dict elements for which **my_method(foo, bar)** returns a value that is greater than a pre-defined limit.

How can I do this?

Comment: `filter(..., key=lambda foo: my_method(foo, bar) < threshold)`. Using `sorted` as a name is a bad idea. It will mask the builtin

Comment: How are you sorting dict? Dicts do not have an order... I assume you either have an [Ordered Dict](https://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.7.html#pep-372-adding-an-ordered-dictionary-to-collections) or you want it to return a [list of tuples that represent a dict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/sort-a-python-dictionary-by-value)?